# How to make a fix spacing position in any screen size

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have created a container with element inside, however when the screen is resize the element moves, would like it to have a fix position, i tried the following

```css
.ClassName {
    position:relative;
    left:2%;
}
    
.ClassName {
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
```

the container size is 1140px  so when I go to 1024px
the element get moved

```css
.container { max-width:1140px; widht:100%;}
.element1 { width:250px;}
#one { left:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="element1" id="one"></div>
     <div class="element1"></div>
     <div class="element1"></div>
     <div class="element1"></div>
</div>
```

I am thinking of subtracting the left value while the screen is being reduced but not sure how to do that  automatically

Answer (score 0):

I think you should resize the width of the element when you resize the screen.
You have 4 elements and each element is 250px and you have margin-left 10px.
it is meant to let your elements in a line, the screen should be at least 1010px.

You have two solutions to fix it.
Give the element in CSS. max-width: 250px; and width: 100%;
Or use @media screen to change style when the screen is resizing.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1028px){
 .element1{
  width: 200px;
 }
}
```